# transform string to decimal

Tags: c#

This feels wrong:

```
private decimal ConvertStringToDecimal(string decimalString, decimal defaultReturnValue)
{
    var returnDecimal = defaultReturnValue;

    try
    {
    returnDecimal = decimal.Parse(decimalString.Trim());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    // naughty
    }

    return returnDecimal;
}
```

but I think this is the only way to transform a string from a third party system to a decimal whilst returning a default. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to improve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest and most clean way would be to use `decimal.TryParse()` like so

```
private decimal ConvertStringToDecimal(string decimalString, decimal defaultReturnValue)
{
    decimal result;
    if (decimal.TryParse(decimalString.Trim(), out result))
    {
        return result;
    }

    return defaultReturnValue;
}
```

Using exceptions to control the returned value isn't a good way, especially if there are better methods to use.

Your indentation is off but I assume that thats a posting issue.

Comment: oh yeah - forgot about that method (-:

Comment: I really don't understand why they did it this way, Java also uses exceptions for flow control when converting to numeric values. It's comforting that c# has a better alternative. Hopefully Java will “borrow” this method in the next version :)

Comment: @Morgen I have mixed feelings about the out parameter, it feels so low level...

Comment: @Caridorc I agree, still much better than throwing an exception as you don't incur the cost of building a stack trace every time the user gives you a malformed number. Returning a Maybe/Option type would be even better.

Answer (score 3):

You can write the equivalent shorter, using the ternary operator `?:` and `decimal.tryParse`, like this:

```
private decimal ConvertStringToDecimal(string decimalString, decimal defaultReturnValue)
{
    decimal value = decimal.TryParse(decimalString, out value) ? value : defaultReturnValue;
    return value;
}
```